# realtek 8188cus doesn't work

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I'm new to Ubuntu, very new, and doesn't really know if what I'm doing is correct.

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 5 days ago, my tplink tl-wn723n wifi usb adapter connects to the wifi router but keeps asking for the password, searched google and found out it's a bug, my tplink is version 2 so that means it has rtl8188cus.

so far, what I've tried are:

blacklisting certain modules, I'm not sure if I did it correctly: to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` I added:

```
# Blacklist native realtek 8188cus drivers
blacklist rtl8192c
blacklist rtl8192c_common
blacklist rtlwifi
```

downloaded the driver from realtek, for 8188cus, extracted it, then ran `sudo bash install.sh`. after restarting, I don't get wifi on my network anymore.

I also tried doing the `rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms_1.6_all` made by tim, at some point. I was able to install this, but now, when I try to, it won't. It would say:

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: dkms (>= 1.95)
```

please help, i may need noob instructions todo this

Answer (score 3):

First of all, ensure you have the necessary prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git
```

Clone the updated driver with `git`:

```
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
```

Set it up as a DKMS module:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
```

Build and install the driver, you may need check the version here (e.g. 1.9 may change):

```
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.9
```

Refresh the module list:

```
sudo depmod -a
```

Ensure the native (and broken) kernel driver is blacklisted:

```
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

Let's not take any chances. Instruct Ubuntu to load the new driver when it starts up.

```
echo 8192cu | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Reboot.

### You're done.

<sub>Thanks to [P. Varet](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) for this awesome fix.</sub>

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.